# How to make div with image disappear behind Menu-Item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with a div, this div contains an image. I also have a menu bar, which expands when hovered. The image should lie under the menu bar then, and not be visible while the expanded menu is 'above' it. However, it does not do that: The image clearly lies on top of the menu. How could I fix this and have the image disappear? Did I do something wrong in my CSS?

```css
body {
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #F6F8FB;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: AlegreyaSansSC-Light;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #637F92;
  letter-spacing: 0.52px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 126px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav li:hover {
  /*background-color: #0B619B;*/
  /*opacity: 0.1;*/
  /*color: #637F92;*/
  background: rgb(221, 232, 241);
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(221, 232, 241, 0.95);
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*removes bullet points*/
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F6F8FB;
  min-width: 70px;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  padding: 70px 126px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown-content:hover {
  background: rgb(221, 232, 241);
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(221, 232, 241, 0.95);
}
.nav li:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.logo-bar {
  background-color: white;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  height: 63px;
  width: 56px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  /*border: 3px solid #73AD21;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Wilkommen</li>
    <li>Angebot
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Unternehmen
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li>Hallo</li>
        <li>Hallo2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Anfahrt</li>
    <li>Kontakt</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- LOGO BAR -->
<div class="logo-bar">
  <div class="logo">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 63 56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 63 56;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {
          fill: #0D629C;
          stroke: #FFFFFF;
          stroke-width: 0.3177;
          stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }
        .st1 {
          fill: #F2DE20;
        }
      </style>
      <g id="XMLID_3_">
        <path id="XMLID_13_" class="st0" d="M29.6,44.8c5,3.6,7.4,8.8,0.9,9.9c-8.8,1.5-20.3-2.7-26.1-9.5c-4.3-5,1.2-7.4,7.5-6.9
         C18.3,38.8,24.6,41.2,29.6,44.8z" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code (HTML, CSS, etc.)

Comment: We need the minimum information necessary, including HTML, CSS, and any Javascript you have that pertains to this situation before anyone can give you a specific answer. The basics of what I can say is that you need to change the z-index of your menu to be higher.

Comment: I've added the relevant parts of the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things were wrong: your dropdown menu didn't have a z-index high enough to sit on top of the SVG, and your `.dropdown-menu` code had an RGBA background which was 95% opaque (meaning it was a little bit see through).

By changing around those two things, I *believe* this is the effect you wanted.

```css
body {
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #F6F8FB;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
svg {
  z-index: -1
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: AlegreyaSansSC-Light;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #637F92;
  letter-spacing: 0.52px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 126px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav li:hover {
  /*background-color: #0B619B;*/
  /*opacity: 0.1;*/
  /*color: #637F92;*/
  background: rgb(221, 232, 241);
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(221, 232, 241, 0.95);
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*removes bullet points*/
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F6F8FB;
  min-width: 70px;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  padding: 70px 126px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}
.dropdown-content:hover {
  background: rgb(221, 232, 241);
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  
}
.nav li:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.logo-bar {
  background-color: white;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  height: 63px;
  width: 56px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  /*border: 3px solid #73AD21;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Wilkommen</li>
    <li>Angebot
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Unternehmen
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li>Hallo</li>
        <li>Hallo2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Anfahrt</li>
    <li>Kontakt</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- LOGO BAR -->
<div class="logo-bar">
  <div class="logo">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 63 56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 63 56;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {
          fill: #0D629C;
          stroke: #FFFFFF;
          stroke-width: 0.3177;
          stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }
        .st1 {
          fill: #F2DE20;
        }
      </style>
      <g id="XMLID_3_">
        <path id="XMLID_13_" class="st0" d="M29.6,44.8c5,3.6,7.4,8.8,0.9,9.9c-8.8,1.5-20.3-2.7-26.1-9.5c-4.3-5,1.2-7.4,7.5-6.9
         C18.3,38.8,24.6,41.2,29.6,44.8z" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using z-index to position the image behind the menu bar.

```
image {z-index: -1;}
```

Comment: `img{ z-index : -1} `

Comment: I can take a look if you have a dev link somewhere.